# regex to get text only between two characters

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

This is probably not that easy as you think :)

I want to match something exactly between a character and 2 characters, and only between these two. The first character is ! and the second is ']

Example string: `Hello 123 !get this text'] hello 1234`

So I want to capture only "get this text",

E.g. this should also only catch "get this text" :

```
Hello 123 ! hello !get this text'] hello 1234
```

and not the "hello !get this text"

This regex seems to only work on the first example: `(?<=!)[^}]*(?='])`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
(?<=!)[^!]+?(?='\])
```

- `(?<=!)`: Look behind for an exclamation mark `!`.
- `[^!]+?`: Match one or more characters which are not exclamation marks, and do this lazily one character at a time, checking the following expression after each character matched to know when to stop.
- `(?='\])`: Look ahead to see if there is a literal `'` which is followed by a literal `]`.

Here is [Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kL0kQ2) in PHP but it makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @user2969412 Check the [about] page to see how this Q&A site works please.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simpler regexes with -split and -replace:

```
$t1 = "Hello 123 !get this text'] hello 1234"
$t2 = "Hello 123 ! hello !get this text'] hello 1234"

($t1,$t2) -split '!' -match "']" -replace "'].+",''

get this text
get this text
```